# Is the permeability of normal shellac (flakes dissolved in spirits) the same as Zinsser B-I-N sealer?

Tags: walls, paint, sealing, primer

I've made a whole batch of clear shellac for sealing ceiling and concrete floors in a heavily nicotine damaged apartment.
But I'm worried now that there may be some differences between them, such as permeability.
Can anyone ease my fears?

I'm simply too poor to pay $130 per room to paint BIN sealer (that's how much it costs here... and I'm laying it on thin).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer this question but can tell you what we did to get the answers we needed.  We emailed (or you could call for) the specific questions we needed answered to the manufacturer of the Shellac product...Zinsser, by Rust-Oleum.  They responded in a couple of days and were very helpful.